# elisp: call org-todo, then find the resulting :LOGBOOK: drawer in the same function

Tags: org-mode

Suppose I have the following setup:

```
(setq org-todo-keywords '((type "TODO(t!)" "IN-PROGRESS(i)" "WAITING(w)" "|" "DONE(d)"))) 
(setq org-log-into-drawer t)
```

So when I change the status of an item to TODO, the state change would be logged into the :LOGBOOK: drawer. the drawer would be created if it doesn't exist.

I'm trying to make use of this to create the :LOGBOOK: drawer by calling (org-todo "TODO")

I have this function:

```
(defun org-todo-test() 
  (interactive) 
  (org-todo "TODO") 
  (search-forward ":LOGBOOK:"))
```

I put my cursor on a heading and call this function, I always get an error saying "search failed" even though the :LOGBOOK: drawer is created. It is as though the drawer isn't available in the buffer until (org-todo-test) has completed running.

Using (org-todo) to generate the drawer is probably a bad idea. But I'm still curious to know what the problem is here. Also if someone can share a better way to create the drawer it'd be great.

Comment: The logging is done via `(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'org-add-log-note 'append)`. So if you want to add a test append it to `post-command-hook` after the call to `org-todo`.

Comment: Thank you so much.